# Listening to a store event

Tags: ember.js

In my `App.NodesIndexController` I am doing something like:

```
destroyAllRecords: function () {
    var _this=this;
    Bootstrap.ModalPane.popup({
        heading: 'Warning',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to delete all nodes?',
        primary: 'Ok',
        secondary: 'Cancel',
        showBackdrop: true,
        callback: function(opts, event) {
            if (opts.primary) {
                _this.forEach(function(node) {
                    console.log('Deleting node %o', node);
                    node.deleteRecord();
                });
                var store = _this.get('store').commit();
                store.commit();
                store.on('didDelete', toggleMessageTray.bind(this, 'All nodes have been successfully deleted'));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But I actually do not know how to listen to the "store has been updated" event. I do not want to listen to the individual `nodes` `didDelete` events, but to a global store event, triggered after the commit has been performed.

Three questions:

1. Is there such an event?
2. Where are store events defined? I do not see documentation about it ([this](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-a-store/) is the only documentation I know about the store)
3. Is there a better way to delete all records than to delete each one of them in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

First of all good question! Let me try to give you a **opinionated** answer.

> Is there such an event?

As far as I know there is lamentably no such event on the store to listen to.

> Where are store events defined? I do not see documentation about it (this is the only documentation I know about the store)

Since ember-data is not yet production ready, the only real truth is in the source code and the inline comments there. But generally when persisting changes to the backend and depending to your setup the involved classes are, the [`Store`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js), the [`RESTAdapter`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js) and the [`JSONSerializer`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js), have a look there, you can extend all of those classes to make them work as you want.

> Is there a better way to delete all records than to delete each one of them in a loop?

Yes and no, by defining `bulkCommit` to `true` on your adapter only one call will be made to the backend with a hash of all records, but **only** in the case of creating records **(thanks @MilkyWayJoe for correcting me, see comment below)**, but this involves obviously that your backend can deal with that, if it does this can of course improve performance.

IMHO you where better of by extending the default `RESTAdapter` and writing you own adapter and hook into the method [`didDeleteRecords`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/308b13ea8ec3d1e59baba90aefd210be9dac866a/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L356) since this method is invoked by the adapter when all records are being deleted.

So, I hope my answer helps you making the right choice - this means using ember-data and writing your own adapter or going with plain old `ajax` calls to deal with all server stuff aka:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON(...);
  }
});
```

If you decide to abandon ember-data, as a starting point take a look at the app build for [discourse.org](http://discourse.org), [repo here](https://github.com/discourse/discourse). It's build without ember-data and can serve as a good place to see how things can be done. Also worth mentioning is this [blog post](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html) which goes into detail on how the discourse.org drives it's site without ember-data.

Comment: I like your answer, but I honestly didn't know you could `bulkCommit` with `DELETE`. Most often than not, I see people doing `POST` passing all the ids as the request data. Another common approach is to have the "node" as a resource, so you can delete this node and in the server you delete the child records, but would still need to sync the store for the children

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, thank you! hmm, now you make me doubt... I'll have a deeper look and correct my answer :)

Comment: I could be totally wrong tho :) if there's a `didDeleteRecords` in the API, it should probably fire when a bulk deletion is complete... so I'm might be wrong indeed

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, corrected my answer. As for the `didDeleteRecords` you are right, it's not in the public API, but I guess by writing your own adapter you could hook into it, obviously not future proof, just wanted to point to some relevant method